# Разные типа одна форма?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Помогите решить задачу...

Есть 3 типа материала
Новость, Статья, Видео

У всех трех по сути одинаковые поля, но в каждом есть 3-4 разных поля свойственных только для определенного типа.
Так как у меня в Post есть выбор типа соответственно и форма одна а вываливать в одну форму все это бредово.

Да и появилась проблема с валидацией. К примеру я заполняю тип новость и поля test мне не нужно, оно нужно для типа Видео, а в валидации прописано что оно обязательно.

Как правильно сделать так что бы при выборе типа были только нужные поля и валидация именно этих полей?

Или как вариант разделить все это на 3 разных формы.
К примеру создать /news/add и во вьюхе сделать выбор типа, если тип новость, то рендерим форму новости.

Как правильно помогите решить.

Answer (score 1):

1. Для валидаций стоит использовать FormObject'ы. [Вот](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects) пример статьи по теме. Общие валидации оставить в модели или вынести в родительский форм-обджект.
2. Скорее всего здесь нужен JS. Я бы начал с попытки скрывать / показывать / энейблить /дисейблидь инпуты.